# Creating Service Principle for a specific Azure user

Tags: azure-devops

In the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node) it talks about creating a service principle for the current user. I want to have more of a hierarchical security structure. I would be the current user and I want to have "super-user" or admin rights to this key vault. However I have created another user that would have lower access rights. For both of these scenarios I gather I need to generate a unique service principle name. How do I generate a service principle name for an arbitrary Azure User?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create another service principal name under your current account for this created user. And you just need to assign the lower access rights to the key vault for this service principal. Then the user can access to the key vault with this service principal which has lower access permission.

An Azure [service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-4.5.0) is an identity created for use with applications, hosted services, and automated tools to access Azure resources. You can create as many as service principals as you want for different access permissions.  If you want to generate a service principal under the created user account, you might have to login as this created user. Otherwise, i am afraid it cannot be done.

You can also set the access permission for this user to this key vault directory without using service principal. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-set-policy)

```
az keyvault set-policy --name keyVaultName --object-id userObjectId --secret-permissions permissions --key-permissions permissions
```

You can get the user's Object id with below command: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/group-permissions-for-apps#users)

```
az ad user show --id <email-address-of-user>
```